# A fast way to draw/update colors of a 2d array of squares in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a game in JavaScript which has a 2d array of squares that update their background colors every frame.

So far I've been using a borderless DOM table for this task by setting the style.backgroundColor of each cell every frame, but it's fairly slow. Is there a way to do this faster?

Comment: Instead of using DOM, start using HTML5 canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of computation directly drawing the squares in a single canvas should be faster (JS compiles to rather efficient native code in these days, and the small overhead that you would get is probably much less than the overhead of dealing with the DOM and `.style` would introduce).

Of course only testing with the devices/browsers you need to support can provide real answers (and note that things may change over time).

Example code:

```js
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   
setInterval(function(){
    for (var y=0; y<256; y+=16) {
        for (var x=0; x<256; x+=16) {
            var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
            var g = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
            var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 16, 16);
        }
    }
}, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=256 height=256></canvas>
```